# Sitecore package uninstall

Tags: sitecore

What is the best way to uninstall a package or a module in Sitecore?

I've seen suggestions to do it manually, but it is not very convenient way, especially when there were many templates, items, layouts, renderings and static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Sitecore Rocks to create an "anti-package."

https://www.sitecore.net/nl-be/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/trevor-campbell/posts/2013/02/28-days-of-sitecore-rocks-package-management-part-1.aspx

Comment: That is a very good approach, thanks! But unfortunately it is not applicable for previously installed packages. Or at least it will be needed to reinstall old package to have an opportunity to create an "anti-package" for it.

Comment: It seems to be the best way. "Anti-package" not only uninstalls, but also reverts overridden changes.

Answer (score 2):

I have never tested the Package History module that was mentioned, so I cannot comment as to whether that approach works.

Open the .zip file for the original package and look through the XML to figure out what files the package installed. Then back up your site and remove files and configuration nodes the package installed(assuming you are confident you understand what purpose the files and nodes have and what other components may rely on them). The Package History module may be taking this same approach, but you need to be certain that what you are deleting is not going to break anything.

Otherwise, I would recommend restoring to a backup made before you installed the package.

Comment: Yes, thanks, and this is exactly how Sitecore advises to do it (just found in their Knowledge base - https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/916660). They say: "Sitecore CMS does not currently provide an automated way for removing packages installed using the Installation Wizard application. You can only remove packages manually."